# How do you destroy the D.D.T. in Bloons Tower Defense 6?

Tags: bloons-td-6

So I've recently found out about the D.D.T. ([Dark Dirigible Titan](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Dirigible_Titan_(D.D.T.))) and well, every time I try to destroy it, it just makes it past my defense. It has the property of a lead, black, M.O.A.B., pink, and camo bloons!

My defense can't handle the D.D.T. Is there a way to beat it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Bloons Wiki Page on the D.D.T.](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Dirigible_Titan_(D.D.T.)), there are very limited ways to take it out.

It would appear that a Monkey Intelligence Bureau is the most surefire way to allow your towers to hit the D.D.T. Certain heroes, like Gwendolin and Striker Jones, can also damage the D.D.T., and should be placed in an optimal spot on your map to hit them as often as possible. Some notable additions from that page include:

1. Super Glue can fully stun the D.D.T.
2. Maim MOAB and Cripple MOAB (from the top Sniper upgrade path) can fully stun the D.D.T.
3. Any "hot" modifier on a Monkey (ex. Hot Shots from the tack shooter, White Hot Spikes from the Spike trap, Hot Shot Grapeshot from the Monkey Ship, and others)
4. Super Monkey upgraded with the top path (must be Plasma or higher, including Sun Avatar, Sun Temple, and True Sun God), though the tradeoff for Sun Temple and True Sun God is to consume surrounding towers as sacrifices.

Comment: What about a D.D.T. rush, like on round 99? I should use multi-hit towers, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that having one 5th tier tower is usually enough to survive round 90, and three or four thoughtfully-selected 5th tier towers by round 100 makes banded DDTS and the BAD a breeze.

There are strategies using only 4th tier towers to survive DDTs, and some especially experienced players can squeak by with 3rd tier towers. And you want to put some thought into the towers you pick. For example, Cripple MOAB Sniper will easily handle round 90, but it can't handle the rush on round 95 by itself. And Guardian of the Forest Druid on a short map can't take out the round 90 DDTs by itself but can help out dramatically on round 95 by providing significant damage to all of the DDTS in the rush.

But when I'm playing a standard game of Bloons and have the freedom to pick my own strategy with plenty of money, I aim to have at least one 5th tier by round 90 and the economy to add several others by round 100.